# Meteor deploy on Heroku Error deploying Node

Tags: node.js, meteor, heroku, deployment

I built a Meteor app, and it runs on my local machine, where I have meteor installed.

I have never deployed an app online, and am trying to put the app on heroku.

I first tried to use buildpack/jordansissel/heroku-buildpack-meteor.git, but I got an error "Meteor requires Node v0.10.41 or later"

I then tried to use buildpack/michaltakac/meteor-buildpack-horse.git but it failed to push because it couldn't unpack Node.

Lastly I've tried kevinseguin/heroku-buildpack-meteor.git but I get lots of warnings about npm depricated http://prntscr.com/bewzak

When I look at the logs it says "Slug compilation failed: failed to compile Node.js app"

I also get Error: MONGO_URL must be set in environment

I don't know enough to understand what the errors are, or how to get my app deployed

Image of errors: http://prntscr.com/bex0av

my goal it to get the site on gr-fireworks.herokuapp.com

I contacted Heroku helpdesk and they said they couldn't help me because the issue was outside the scope of Heroku Support.

I tried to reach out to Snap CI who said they were successful in deploying it, but when I try to type in exactly what they did, I am still getting the error about Node https://snap-ci.com/ankitsri11/Fireworks/branch/master/logs/defaultPipeline/1/Heroku?back_to=build_history

My repository I'm trying to deloy is on git at github.com/jschwarzwalder/Fireworks

Comment: this is multiple questions in one, you should visit https://forums.meteor.com/ for the community support, or #node.js channel on irc

Comment: "Meteor requires Node v0.10.41 or later" : basically you need to install a newer version of node, check the version with :  node -v

Comment: "I also get Error: MONGO_URL must be set in environment" : google heroku mongo setup

Comment: I've posted a guide in this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39042175/error-on-heroku-meteor-app/41866690#41866690

Maybe following the steps helps solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

From description of your problem I can conclude you need to do 2 things on your app's Heroku dashboard (Settings tab):

1. Add `MONGO_URL` environment variable that points to your Mongo DB database. You can create mongo instance on external service or use mLab Heroku addon (it has free plan).

So your environment variables may look like: [image: this]

Also, you may need to add `METER_SETTINGS` if you use `--settings settings.json` and `ROOT_URL` - URL of you app `gr-fireworks.herokuapp.com` (is required).

2. Set [this](https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse) buildpack:

[image: buildpack settings]

Ensure you have `.git` at the end of url.

Now you can deploy your app using single command (if you setup Heroku Toolbelt and `heroku` remote points Heroku's app repository):

```
$ git push heroku master
```