# Error on heroku meteor app

Tags: meteor, heroku

I deployed my web app on heroku with the following procedures given in this document: https://medium.com/@leonardykris/how-to-run-a-meteor-js-application-on-heroku-in-10-steps-7aceb12de234#.93vvydncs

Then my app was not running and the logs said that meteor needs node v 0.10.41 or above.

I changed my buildpack to - https://github.com/kevinseguin/heroku-buildpack-meteor.git as per the solution in [Meteor requires Node v0.10.41 or later Error on heroku deployment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36347815/meteor-requires-node-v0-10-41-or-later-error-on-heroku-deployment).

Then I get the error:

> 2016-08-19T14:50:27.547793+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=dss-society.herokuapp.com request_id=c116c227-b93e-482f-b17e-ec198d65fcf6 fwd="182.64.121.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
>
> 2016-08-19T14:50:28.650907+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=dss-society.herokuapp.com request_id=7ecbfb98-2ee4-4df9-a503-08d013ca8c4a fwd="182.64.121.74" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

Now I don't know what to do next. Need help.

My app url on heroku staging is: https://dss-society.herokuapp.com/

My config of heroku has MONGODB_URI, MONGOLAB_URI, and MONGO_URL, all having the same values. Also it has PAPERTRAIL_API_TOKEN and ROOT_URL which is set to https://dss-society.herokuapp.com

My meteor version is 1.3.4.1.

I hope to get some solution over this. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The buildpack you are using does not seem to work. Try and use:
https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse

So:

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/AdmitHub/meteor-buildpack-horse.git
```

I've copied and replaced parts of the guide which you can find here:
https://github.com/JaySheombar/meteor-on-heroku

Answer (score -1):

I experienced same issue last week. You can look for the specific reason by typing `heroku logs --app <appname>`. In most cases, it was because the version of node your buildpack uses is not aligned with the version of node meteor uses. For Meteor 1.4+, it uses node 4.5.0 so you may need a buildpack that installs the same version of node. I created a guide for it [here](https://meteorcoder.wordpress.com/2016/09/24/how-to-deploy-meteor-apps-with-heroku/).